# How can I filter table columns using OR logic as apposed to AND

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, filtering

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fks37/)

I have an html table:

```
_A_B_C_D_
|0|1|0|1|
|0|1|0|0|
|1|0|0|1|
```

I want to filter *non-zero* columns. Using jQuery dataTables (not a hard requirement, just what I am currently using) I execute the following filter:

```
// value is the column index, true simply informs the filter method to use regex
dataTable.fnFilter("[^0]", value, true);
```

However, filtering multiple columns creates an **AND** filter. Thus:

```
dataTable.fnFilter("[^0]", 0 /*A*/, true); 
dataTable.fnFilter("[^0]", 3 /*D*/, true);
```

would create the following

```
_A_B_C_D_
|1|0|0|1|
```

I need **OR** behavior though which would create the following table:

```
_A_B_C_D_
|0|1|0|1|
|1|0|0|1|
```

Where *Column A* is non-zero **OR** *Column D* is non-zero. I cannot think of any way to implement this with my current structure.

How can I filter table columns using OR logic as apposed to AND?

Comment: The doc says you can pass null as the second parameter to filter all columns, I haven't tried it though.  `dataTable.fnFilter("[^0]", null, true);`  Won't work if you need to be specific about which columns are ORed.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I could find a way to send an array of indeces instead of a single index or global.

Comment: You can roll your own filtering functions too:  [link](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your fiddle as a model I updated it to provide the functionality that I believe you want.

I extend the dataTables filtering on each click of a checkbox:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function (settings, data, index) {
        var s = [0, 3, 5]; // columns to filter
        for (var i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
            if (data[s[i]] != 0) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

Fully integrated into fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fks37/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you might need that functionality wrapped up into some user-interface, you may go and check out [this DataTables plug-in](https://github.com/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter), in addition to conventional 'AND'-logic you may apply 'OR'-filtering.