# How to filter jQuery Tablesorter by multiple columns using OR logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, tablesorter

I am looking for a means of doing an OR filter against multiple columns in jQuery TableSorter much like [DataTable Multiple column OR filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663313/how-can-i-filter-table-columns-using-or-logic-as-apposed-to-and).  I upgraded to 2.21.5.

I have a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Omnilord/4mVfu/4665/).  I have tried to do [filter_functions](http://jsfiddle.net/Omnilord/4mVfu/4666/):

```
    filter_functions: {
        '.filter-OR': function (e, n, f, i, $r, c) {
           /*
            manually check the row for all columns
            with a class of filter-OR
           */
        }
    }
```

but applying a function to any classes overrides the filter-availOnly option.

Not sure how to move forward with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding the request, maybe try something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/4701/)):

```
$(function () {
    var $table = $('table'),
        // get 'filter-OR' column indexes
        orColumns = $('.filter-OR').map(function (i) {
            return this.cellIndex;
        }).get(),
        filterfxn = function (e, n, f, i, $r, c) {
            var col, v,
                showRow = false,
                content = [];
            $r.children().filter(function (indx) {
                if (orColumns.indexOf(indx) > -1) {
                    v = (c.$filters.eq(indx).find('.tablesorter-filter').val() || '').toLowerCase();
                    showRow = showRow || $(this).text().toLowerCase() === v;
                }
            });
            return showRow;
        };

    $table.tablesorter({
        theme: 'green',
        widgets: ['uitheme', 'zebra', 'columns', 'filter'],
        sortReset: true,
        sortRestart: true,
        widthFixed: true,
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_functions: {
                '.filter-OR': {
                    'Yes': filterfxn,
                    'No' : filterfxn
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Mottie, that solution doesn't filter properly when changing Test 2 to "No"

I'm using the script from http://jsfiddle.net/Omnilord/4mVfu/4674/ currently, but I haven't accepted it as an answer because I am fairly certain I have overlooked a more elegant implementation, but I have not figure it out myself.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem. I've fixed the code & the demo link in the above answer.

Answer (score 3):

The way of using filter_functions is a bit different from the way you were using it in your example.

You have to provide the columns to which the filter function will be applied as well as a key representing the value of the select that will trigger the function.

You do that in the form of an object whose keys are the columns and the value of those keys is another object whose keys are the values of the select and the values of those keys the function that will be triggered.

For instance:

```
filter_functions: {
    1: {// Column one...
       "Yes" : function() {},//... will trigger the anonymous function when "Yes" is selected.
       "No" : function() {}//... will trigger the anonymous function when "No" is selected.

    }
}
```

If you want an OR you could do something like:

```
function (e, n, f, i, $r, c) {
    return $r.find("td")// For all the tds of this row
    .not(":first")// Avoid checking the first one (usually the ID)
    .filter(function (_, el) {// filter all tds which value differs from "Yes"
        return $(el).text() === "Yes";
    })
    .length > 0;// If length is bigger than one it means we have at least one "Yes", therefore we tell tablesorter not to filter this row.
};
```

Same applies to "No" except we change the value that we'll be checking.
Wrapping everything up and making it a bit tidier we have:

```
var checker = function (value) {
    return function (e, n, f, i, $r, c) {
        return $r.find("td")
            .not(":first")
            .filter(function (_, el) {
            return $(el).text() === value;
        })
            .length > 0;
    };
}, objChecker = function () {
    return {
        "Yes": checker("Yes"),
        "No": checker("No")
    };
};

$('table').tablesorter({
    // Here goes your code to set up the table sorter ...
        filter_functions: {
            1: objChecker(),
            2: objChecker(),
            3: objChecker()
        }
    }
});
```

You can check it out in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/4669/)**

Hope it helps.

Comment: that was just the bread crumb I needed to get the solution!  What I have right now is found at http://jsfiddle.net/Omnilord/4mVfu/4674/ but I am not sure it's hardened against errors properly.  The only problem with your solution was the "filter-availOnly" issue which dynamically generates the select options.  "Yes" and "No" were easy, concise scope, but I also need this filtering to work for variable options.  I am hoping the example linked contributes to the body of knowledge.